# Android Studio Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I wonder if anyone has documentation on how to implement Google Maps v2 on Android Studio, the official documentation does not explain this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well these steps worked good to me

**First**, update the version of your android studio to version 0.5.4 or later

**Second**, make the project as you want only recommend you to create at least 17 ​​API for Google Maps V2 run with no problem and select Google Maps Activity

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Third**, the good thing about this update is that Android Studio in Manifest.xml and Activity are already configured to do the test directly

[image]

**Fourth**, do not forget to configure and enter your own api_key

[image]

[image]

**Fifth**: I recommend to you use Genymotion to test your apps with maps, the emulator is much easier to manage, faster and easier to install Google Play Services

http://www.genymotion.com/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCRNqCXGNK0

[image]